# Issue while creating locale for greece

Tags: android, localization

I am facing issue while setting locale for greece. I am creating folder as `values-el_GR` and put my `strings.xml` in but it gives me error and I am also not able to see country flag (for greece) that we can see in string resources tab.

is that something I missed?

Comment: should not it be values-el?

Comment: `Greek, Greece (el_GR)             2.3` - API level 2.3+ is required.

Comment: and the Greecian flag is in `/res/drawable-el_GR` as well?

Comment: ... and where is the flag image? I'd call it "flag" and put it in the localized folder. Anyway, it seems that @18446744073709551615 is right: try removing `_GR` and just use `el`

Comment: Yes, this I already know (I see it in my translations). I'm not supporting languages with a "strange alphabet". 1 - because I'm ignorant (OK, I could use Google tarnslator, to make FUNNY TRANSLATIONS, I already see it in the 5 languages I support). 2 - because I still support Froyo, so MANY languages (also Portuguese) aren't supported (until Android 2.3+).